# How to pass data through a redirect to a view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes

How can I pass data from a controller after it performs certain action to a view through a `redirect()` if I have a get route for it?

The logic of the app is to redirect with an `user_id` to a view where the user will select its username after successfully verified its email.

```
public function confirm($confirmationCode){
 if(!$confirmationCode){
   dd('No se encontró ningún código de verificación en la URL');
 }
 $user = User::where('confirmation_code', $confirmationCode)->first();
 if(!$user){
   dd('Lo sentimos. Este código de confirmación ya ha sido usado.');
 }
 $user->confirmed = 1;
 $user->confirmation_code = null;
 $user_id = $user->user_id;
 $user->save();

 return redirect('assign-username')->with(compact('user_id'));
}
```

The get route:

```
Route::get('assign-username', 'AuthenticationController@showAssignUsernameForm');
```

And the code for the post request of the `assign-user` form.

```
public function assignUsername(){
  $user_id = request()->input('user_id');
  $username = request()->input('username');
  if(User::where('username', '=', $username)->exists()){
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors([
    'username' => 'Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado. Intenta nuevamente'
  ]);
  }else{
    DB::table('user')->where('user_id', $user_id)->update(['username' => $username]);
  }
 }
```

When trying to access to the `$user_id` variable it says it is not defined.

The view's code:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    <section class="hero">
        <h1><span>Ya estás casi listo.</span>Es hora de seleccionar tu nombre de usuario</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form class="form-group"  method="post" action="assign-username">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    @if($errors->has('username'))
                        <span class="help-block" style="color:red">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ session('user_id') }}">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre de usuario">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="send">Registrar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
@endsection
```

Laravel Version: 5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...

**Update**

Storing `$user_id` on a hidden input is a bit risky, how if your user know how to change the value on browser such as Chrome developer console and replace it with another user id?

Rather than storing it on hidden input I would store it as [session flash data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#flash-data), it could be:

```
public function confirm($confirmationCode){
    ....

    session()->flash('user_id', $user_id); // Store it as flash data.

    return redirect('assign-username');
}
```

On `AuthenticationController@showAssignUsernameForm` tell Laravel to keep your `user_id` for next request:

```
public function showAssignUsernameForm() {
    session()->keep(['user_id']);
    // or
    // session()->reflash();

    return view('your-view-template');
}
```

And on your assign username `POST` method you can define the value like this:

```
public function assignUsername(){
    $user_id  = session()->get('user_id');
    $username = request()->input('username');

    if(User::where('username', '=', $username)->exists()) {
        session()->flash('user_id', $user_id); // Store it again.

        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors([
            'username' => 'Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado. Intenta nuevamente'
        ]);
    } else {
        DB::table('user')->where('user_id', $user_id)->update(['username' => $username]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works and thank you for explaining the risk of using a hidden input for important data. (bad practice that got stuck in me because of my professor). However the same thing as commented below is happening: If I introduce an invalid username (one that is already on the database) and then I introduce a valid one it won't save on the DB. I know that it is because it won't longer have the `user_id` on the session, how can I sort this out?

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public function assignUsername(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $request->user_id;
```

Comment: I was passing it to the view into a hidden input but I'll try your approach.

Comment: It didn't work. If I `dd()` the `$user_id` variable it will be null.

Comment: Show the view please.

Comment: Added in the question.

Comment: I don't get it. You're redirecting to `assign-username` which runs `showAssignUsernameForm()` action which shows form (posted view in your question). Why then your form uses `action="assign-username"`? It should be something like `action="{{ action('AuthenticationController@assignUsername') }}"`. Also, why do you use `value="{{ session('user_id') }}"`? It should be `value="{{ $user_id }}"`

Comment: I use that `action` because I have a POST route for it on my routes file. I didn't know about the `action()` helper. I'll  look into it and finally I used the `session()` as suggested above for another user.

Comment: Look at source HTML of the form generated by Laravel. I bet hidden field value is empty. Just use `$user_id`

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing data to the view, to get the information after `with(compact('user_id'))` you must do through `Session` like this:

```
 @if (session('user_id'))
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ session('user_id') }}">           
@endif
```

Comment: It worked as expected. However if I introduce an invalid username (already existent in DB) and then insert a valid one it won't work. If I `dd()` the user it will be blank. Could you help me there? Also, why wasn't my previous approach working and why did yours work?

Comment: if you introduce an invalid username the application take you to the previous page, and there you introduce a valid, right? @AndrésBuitrago

Comment: Yes, it takes me back to show the error but if after that I insert the valid one it won't save anything on the DB.